# KO.Utils.PostJSon returns Null in Controller MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

i am trying to create a Grid using knockout.js by following
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

when i try to post the values from the viwe to controller always i am getting a count=0 value.But whe i try to check whether the data has the view model using alert.it comes as expected.Is there anyone faced/Fixed this issue.kindly highlight me where the error is.

her is my model.

```
public class GiftModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Code in COntroller :

```
         public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var initialState = new[] {
    new GiftModel { Title = "Head First C#", Price = "49.95" },
    new GiftModel { Title = "Head First Js", Price = "78.25" }
        };
        return View(initialState);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<GiftModel> gifts)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Here is what ia ma doing in view.

var initialData = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));

```
var viewModel = { 
    gifts : ko.observableArray(initialData), 

    addGift: function () { 
        this.gifts.push({ Title: "", Price: "" }); 
    },

    removeGift: function (gift) { 
        this.gifts.remove(gift); 
    },

    save: function() { 
        var data = ko.toJSON(this.gifts);
        alert(data);
        ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { gifts: data });
    }
}; 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel,document.body);
```

I have tried with normal Ajax post also.but still i am getting the same thing.

**Edit:** here is waht i am getting in the Alert

[{"Title":"Head First C#","Price":"49.95"},{"Title":"Head First Js","Price":"78.25"}]

**Update :** if i pass the pop up content directly controller can able to identify the data.

```
        var model = [{"Title":"Head First C#","Price":"49.95"},{"Title":"Head First Js","Price":"78.25"}];"Status": "Reserved" }];
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Grid/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: No need to call `ko.toJSON()`. internally, `ko.utils.postJson()` does it for you.

Comment: yes, i have started with that,that didnt give me output then i have moved to Ajax Calls.Thanks @haim770

Comment: Try `ko.utils.postJson(location.href, this.gifts);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i achieved it .

We need to call `ko.toJS(this.gifts)` before sending the data to the request.

Here is the Working Code.

var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

```
var viewModel = { 
    gifts : ko.observableArray(initialData), 

    addGift: function () { 
        this.gifts.push({ Title: "", Price: "" }); 
    },

    removeGift: function (gift) {
        this.gifts.remove(gift);
    },

    Save : function () {

        var ViewModel = ko.toJS(this.gifts);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Grid/Index",
            data: ko.toJSON(ViewModel),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: true,
            complete: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Thanks Ivan.Srb,szpic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ko.toJS` instead of `ko.toJSON`.

**Update**:
Try this (instead of `ko.utils.postJson`):

```
$.ajax({
        url: <your_url>,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
```

Comment: Here is something weird happening.If i pass content i received from the alert directly like below.it can able to identify the data.i have update the Question with that.

Comment: It is really interesting... You could try to create empty array, than fill it by your data and send this array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47950/discussion-between-hsakarp-and-ivan-srb)

Answer (score 0):

I Just want to ask:
You have model:

```
public class GiftModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

co why you are pushing into Price strings while it is double?

```
new GiftModel {/**/, Price = "78.25" }
```

in the link you provided this line looks:

```
new GiftModel { /**/, Price = 78.25 }
```

I'm not saying that will help solve your problem. I'm just curious.

@Update

On the this webpage: [KnockOutJS Homepage](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html)
You can find this line:

```
// To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: 
ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.gifts);
```

Without any use of ko.toJSON(data);
So in you case this will be:

```
ko.utils.postJson(youradress,this.gifts)
```

check this :)

Comment: i am sorry,initially i have that model then after going through all the options,i dont know what to do(:-.going DUMB) , i just changes double to string.SO i changed that .Sorry i havent updated in the Question

Comment: Thanks szpic. i have tried out the entire options,i am getting zero count.Somewhere i am doing mistake.